# dict to remove smart quotes

Tags: python-2.7, text, unicode

```
charmap = [
  (u"\u201c\u201d", "\""),
  (u"\u2018\u2019", "'")
  ]

_map = dict((c, r) for chars, r in charmap for c in list(chars))
fixed = "".join(_map.get(c, c) for c in s)
print fixed
```

I was looking to write a similar script to replace smart quotes and curly apostrophes from text answered here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819586/how-do-i-write-a-custom-encoding-in-python-to-clean-up-my-data/5819787#5819787): Would someone be kind enough to explain the two lines:

```
_map = dict((c, r) for chars, r in charmap for c in list(chars))
fixed = "".join(_map.get(c, c) for c in s)
```

and possibly rewrite them in a longer-winded format with comments to explain what is exactly going on - I'm a little confused whether its an inner/outer loop combo or sequential checking over items in a dictionary.

Comment: What precisely don't you understand about those two lines?

Comment: first line creates a dict by generating tuples (char => replacement), second line applies the dict transformation on each char, defaulting to original value if not in dict.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm unsure if _map is a new dictionary which looks up items in charmap concurrently or in an inner loop with c as list of chars. The second line is a bit easier but I'm unfamiliar with .get (c,c)

Comment: So did you trying printing `_map`? Reading the docs on `dict.get`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, that's the sensible thing to do. I got super confused as to what could actually be printed at that stage - I assumed that most things would kick out errors in printing, _map possibly being unprintable unicode or unicode not printing to a DOS terminal at that point. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
_map = dict((c, r) for chars, r in charmap for c in list(chars))
```

means:

```
_map = {}                     # an empty dictionary
for (c, r) in charmap:        # c - string of symbols to be replaced, r - replacement
    for chars in list(c):     # chars - individual symbol from c
        _map[chars] = r       # adding entry replaced:replacement to the dictionary
```

and

```
fixed = "".join(_map.get(c, c) for c in s)
```

means

```
fixed = ""                          # an empty string   
for c in s:
    fixed = fixed + _map.get(c, c)  # first "c" is key, second is default for "not found"
```

as method `.join`simply concatenates elements of sequence with given string as a separators between them (in this case `""`, i. e. without a separator)

Answer (score 2):

It's faster and more straightforward to use the built in string function `translate`:

```
#!python2
#coding: utf8

# Start with a Unicode string.
# Your codecs.open() will read the text in Unicode
text = u'''\
"Don't be dumb"
“You’re smart!”
'''

# Build a translation dictionary.
# Keys are Unicode ordinal numbers.
# Values can be ordinals, Unicode strings, or None (to delete)
charmap = { 0x201c : u'"',
            0x201d : u'"',
            0x2018 : u"'",
            0x2019 : u"'" }

print text.translate(charmap)
```

Output:

```
"Don't be dumb"
"You're smart!"
```