# Google App Engine Python Mail - error retry logic?

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I have an app and it has given me some errors today because an email has come through with some characters that my script/database does not like.

All the script does is take the email and insert it's meta data into a database. As the script is failing, GAE StackDriver is reporting 500 errors.

My question is this: does anyone know what the retry logic is? I mean, how does GAE receive email and then send it for processing. How many times will it re-process the bad email and/or how many errors will it take before it gives up on the email?

Any tips, info or documentation would be great as this doesn't answer the question: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api

Comment: I suspect the resending may be controlled by the sending server.  You may be able to trap and log the error, which should stop the resends - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012489/5320906 for a way to this.

Comment: I think you may be right about the sending server making the retries - that would make sense.