# Unable to retrieve original character having special number in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am decoding a string that contains below special character with  number i.e "こんにちは①".

Base64 format for these character= 'GyRCJDMkcyRLJEEkTy0hGyhC'

After converting the base64 to bytes(s_bytes) , when I am executing decode command ,It is throwing below error.

```
>>> s_decode=s_bytes.decode('iso-2022-jp')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'iso2022_jp' codec can't decode bytes in position 13-14: illegal multibyte sequence
```

So can somebody explain if this is happening due to  any limitation in python?

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3. Python 2 stopped getting security updates several years ago. The updated `email` library in Python 3.6+ is a lot better for these kinds of things.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0208 the character "②" is part of a special extension set called "NEC special characters" (JIS X 0208 is part of the character set of ISO-2022-JP). This extension set does not seem to be supported by the decoder for ISO-2022-JP that is included in Python's builtin codecs library.

Comment: In other words, Python is stricter about the spec than the other decoder you are trying. You'd basically have to implement your own variant of ISO-2022-JP in Python to get the desired result. (It's not terribly hard, but seems like overkill for a single character in a single, technically malformed message.)

Comment: @tripleee- I am not sure about the logic If i have to implement my own variant of ISO-2022-JP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819586/how-do-i-write-a-custom-encoding-in-python-to-clean-up-my-data has some notes on how to create a custom encoding. Some additional hooks are necessary if you want to use the encoding directly from the `email` module; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819586/how-do-i-write-a-custom-encoding-in-python-to-clean-up-my-data though maybe also the `email.charset` module's documentation. As of Python 3.12 there are still some gaps in both documentation and functionality.

Comment: I don't think you will find anyone who is willing and able to contribute a solution for such an old Python version, though. Perhaps if you asked about Python 3.8+ you would get an answer which could more or less be backported to Python 2.

Comment: @tripleee As an workaround, if someone is willing to give the answer in python 3.8+. I would love to have that.

Comment: adding a python 3.x answer

Comment: @Andj It will be helpful if you could also provide me any document link stating that extension set isn't part of the iso-2022-jp codec. Also I am wondering why there is incompatibility between pyhton  & microsoft use of ISO-2022-JP as it is international standard encoding.

Comment: @RoushanAnand there is no documentation on it unfortunately. Encoding specs get revised over time, implementations may fall out of step or make different choices. There are lots of instances where encodings may differ between implementations. Ken Lunde's book on CJKV Information processing is useful in this regard. It is a particular problem with legacy CJKV encodings.

Comment: One of the reasons for the WHATWG encoding spec was variation in encoder/decoders across implementations, and also that often encoding metadata is often mislabeled.

Answer (score 4):

First decode the Base64 string:

```py
import base64
seq = base64.b64decode('GyRCJWEhPCVrQXc/Li0iGyhC?=')
print(seq)
# b'\x1b$B%a!<%kAw?.-"\x1b(B'
```

This is a ISO-2022-JP byte sequence. ISO-2022-JP supports switching between a number of different character sets.

`\x1b$B` switches to JIS X 0208-1983 (which uses 2 bytes per character). `\x1b(B` switches to ASCII, so the JIS X 0208-1983 sequence is `%a!<%kAw?.-"`. The problem character is the last character represented by `-"` with the lead byte `\x2D` and the trailing byte `\x22`.

The lead byte corresponds to row 13 of JIS X 0208-1983, an extension set containing NEC special characters.

So `\x2D\x22` is the character ②.

It is important to note that not all encoder/decoder pairs for iso-2022-jp support row 13. Unfortunately, the python codecs do not.

The Windows equivalent, and the WHATWG encoding spec and web browser implementations do.

It is necessary to use an alternative. The `endec` module provides encoding and decoding parsers compatible with WHATWG encoding spec.

Install the module:

```bash
pip install endec
```

Then following from the previous code:

```py
import endec
result = endec.decode(seq, "iso-2022-jp")
print(result)
# メール送信②
```

**Edited:**

As indicated in comments, the `endec` module is in alpha development. There is a lack of support in Python for the Microsoft and Web implementations of ISO-2022-JP, but the usage of the extension characters would be infrequent so it would be prudent to default to core Python codecs and fallback to `endec` as a last resort.

```py
try:
    result = seq.decode('iso-2022-jp')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    result = endec.decode(seq, "iso-2022-jp")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I think endec module itself is in pre-release state as per their description-->
NOTE: This project is in a pre-release state, please do not use it in production workloads.

Comment: So far I haven't found alternative encoding modules. Will search.

Comment: @RoushanAnand use core codecs as default, which should handle most use cases, fallback to `endec` as last resort, using try ... except.